# Example of POST to foursquare API?

Tags: json, api, http, post, foursquare

I'm trying to add a new checkin but I can't figure out how Foursquare wants the to receive the parameters. I have tried a url-encoded string in the body:

```
shout=test&venueId=4a663032f964a5202fc81fe3
```

And I have tried a JSON string in the body (with application/json Content-Type header):

```
{"shout":"test","venueId":"4a4a9f71f964a52004ac1fe3"}
```

But, I always get the error response:

```
meta =     {
    code = 400;
    errorDetail = "Must provide parameter venueId";
    errorType = other;
};
```

What is the correct way to POST to their checkins/add endpoint?

Comment: I see on their docs that sometimes the field is called VENUE_ID and other times venueId. Have you tried the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The venueId must be sent as a POST parameter. The precise method of doing this will depend on the library/language you are using.

For example, to do this using CURL on the command line, you would use

```
curl https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add -F venueId=<the id> -F oauth_token=<the token>
```

Comment: There was something goofy at Foursquare earlier that is fixed now. I had another developer confirm the goofiness and conclusion of said goofiness. It's a post parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error.

The fix for my issue was to include the HTTP header content type like this: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

After that I used a normal post data like this:

text="t"&url=xxx&v=20130224

I noticed the version and the url couldn't be quoted and the url needed to be HTML encoded.